# Which PAYPAL method to use?

Tags: paypal

I am working an e-commerce site which will allow pdfs to be downloaded once payment is done.
So, user will put them in a cart, click buy using paypal and from there will come back to see download link on a success page.
I have implemented PDT.
Not sure which is the best option ? 
Please help. I want to take care of any connection lost scenario too, like user completes payment at PAYPAL and while returning back to our site's success page, connection is lost and for some n days, user couldnt access internet as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the IPN.
Keep a record in your database that has all of the order items.
e.g. Order and Order Items (in 2 tables)

Then send that primary key across as the "custom" variable.

Then your ipn handler page will validate the payment and then email the customer their digital goods.

Comment: you are right. but how we can associate the paypal user with the website's user. and do you send multiple keys (comma separated) for multiple items ?

Comment: You can set the IPN on the web page form. Be sure to the the ipn reference guide for more details.

Comment: I thought Paypal warns developers that IPN is not immediate, and that you must not expect the callback to happen in time to respond to customer's purchases as soon as they return to your site...?